# Value unchanged when another function is called in javascript

Tags: javascript

I was reading an article. It is related to javascript. Here, is a code sample from the article. Please look at below.

```js
function customobject(){ 
this.value = 2; 
} 

customobject.prototype.inc = function(){ 
this.value++;
 } 

function changer(func){ 
func();
 } 

var o = new customobject();
 
alert(o.value);   
o.inc(); 
alert(o.value);  
changer(o.inc); 
alert(o.value);
```

My question is Why is the value for "o.value" unchanged when changer(o.inc) is called ?

Comment: you should log the value of `this` and you will see what happens. the problem is that you call `inc` without the this context. If you want to make it work you have to do `changer(o.inc.bind(o))` . [bind doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Answer (score 3):

`o.inc` is just a reference to the anonymous function:

```
function() { 
    this.value++;
}
```

Whereas `this` is the scope in which the function is executed. So when you run `changer(o.inc)`, `this` is actually pointing to the global, in browsers it's `window`. It doesn't necessarily have anything to do with `o`.

You could bind the scope like this:

```
function changer(func, scope){ 
    func.call(scope); // or apply
} 

changer(o.inc, o);
```

Or simply:

```
function changer(func){ 
    func();
}
changer(o.inc.bind(o));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because Function does not save instance for objects. You have to pass the object as argument so call your function, like this.

```js
function customobject(){ 
    this.value = 2; 
} 

customobject.prototype.inc = function(){
    this.value++;
} 

function changer(o){ 
   o.inc();
} 

var o = new customobject();
 
console.log(o.value);  //It has to print 2 
o.inc();               //Increment to 3
console.log(o.value);  //It has to print 3
changer(o);            //Increment to 4
console.log(o.value);  //It has to print 4
```